# shift offset signals in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following offset signals:

[image]

How can I shift them to a common central position?

I have tried to fix it with

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Result is not satisfactory:

[image]

Signals in numpy file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Jac-wNMDxHMVM0U2xVcEpUNnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How about subtracting the mean from each signal?

Comment: edited with what I have tried